# Window title for javascript print

Tags: javascript, window.open

Found this code to print a javascript element that I modified.  Although I added the `document.title` and the `<title></title>` tags, the window that opens in the regular text editor says `untitled`.

This is usually the situation before the text is saved.  Is there a way to show a title anyway?

```
    var element=document.getElementById(element_id);
    var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window','width=400,height=400,top=100,left=100');

    newWin.document.open();
    newWin.document.title = "Readings on PageLinks";
    newWin.document.write('<html><head><title>'+newWin.document.title+'</title></head><body   onload="window.print()">'+element.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
    newWin.document.close();

    setTimeout(function(){ newWin.close(); },10);
```

Comment: why not: newWin.document.write('<html><head><title>Readings on PageLinks</title>... ?

Comment: That did not make a difference.  I had that first.

Comment: you must of had something different or made a mistake somewhere, as Eran is correct on that, at least for my computer

Comment: What browser are you testing this on?

Comment: I was testing this on Safari.  Like I said I had `<head><title>Readings on PageLinks</title></head>` and that did not make a difference.

Comment: @Eran Medan If I cannot open the preview what must I change in my code to not have the pop up window that shows the document that will be printed.  It is not the same as the preview so I don't want to show the document.  I only want the print dialog.  How do I do that?  Right now the print command shows two windows: one with the document, the other is the print dialog.

Comment: Good question, I don't know actually. If it was me, unless the customer / product owner is really pressing this, I would just leave it as is and move on to the next feature... :) not sure if it's cost effective to correct it if it takes so much effort.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the original code worked for me as well (Chrome, didn't test on other browsers)

```
var element_id = "id1";
var element = document.getElementById(element_id);
var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window', 'width=400,height=400,top=100,left=100');

newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.title = "Readings on PageLinks";
newWin.document.write('<html><head></head><body onload="window.print()">' + element.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
newWin.document.close();

setTimeout(function() {
    newWin.close();
}, 10);​
```

See on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzxph/10/)

Comment: Didn't work on my Opera. The title was `about:blank`, apparently a result of opening the page with empty url string. Your previous suggestion works in Opera, though.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the assignment `newWin.document.title = "Readings on PageLinks";` failed, because there was no `<title>` element in the page at that time.

Thus, `newWin.document.title` was still undefined. Then you concatenated it to the string `<title>'+newWin.document.title+'</title>`, so it got `toString()`-ed as "undefined".

So, just write the title directly into the string

```
newWin.document.write('<html><head><title>Readings on PageLinks</title>...');
```

as Eran Medan suggested in the comments.

This worked for me.

Comment: Though so too, but read again, the title is "Untitled", not "undefined" (e.g. a window that didn't have a title)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a behavior of the editor that's opened with the document.  Until the document is saved, the editor header will say "untitled".  This must be by design.